# Fail to typeset an array spanning multiple pages properly using pdfTex

Tags: arrays

I tried to convert a long list of equations in .tex to .pdf using pdfTex. Those equations were written in the array environment, which spans multiple pages. The pdfTex didn't create a pdf file containing the whole list of equations. Instead, the output file only includes 2 pages. The first page is blank. The second page contains the partial list.

How can I get a pdf file containing the whole list of equations and prevent the blank page? Thanks.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=0pt,landscape]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{ccl}
\frac {\mathrm{d}\left( {{\mathrm{[Test]}} \, \cdot \, {V}_{\mathrm{Test}} } \right) }  {\mathrm{d}{t} }  \; &=& \;  { \, - \, \left( { {{K}_{\mathrm{("Test\;Test\;Test")}} \, \cdot \, {\mathrm{[Test]}} }  \, \cdot \, \left( { {{B}_{\mathrm{("Test\;Test\;Test")}} \, + \, \frac {{\mathrm{v1}}_{\mathrm{("Test\;Test\;Test")}} \, \cdot \, {\mathrm{["Test"]}} }  {{\mathrm{K1}}_{\mathrm{("Test\;Test\;Test")}} \, + \, {\mathrm{["Test"]}} }  }  \, + \, \frac {{\mathrm{v2}}_{\mathrm{("Test\;Test\;Test")}} \, \cdot \, {\mathrm{[Test]}} }  {{\mathrm{K2}}_{\mathrm{("Test\;Test\;Test")}} \, + \, {\mathrm{[Test]}} }  } \right) } \right) } \\ 
&& \\ 
&& \\ 
&& \\ 
&& \\ 
&& \\ 
&& \\ 
&& \\ 
&& \\ 
&& \\ 
&& \\ 
&& \\ 
&& \\ 
&& \\ 
&& \\ 
&& \\ 
&& \\ 
&& \\ 
&& \\ 
&& \\ 
&& \\ 
\; && \;  { \, + \, {V}_{\mathrm{Test}} \, \cdot \, \left( { {{K}_{\mathrm{("Test\;Test\;Test")}} \, \cdot \, {\mathrm{[Test]}} }  \, \cdot \, \left( {{B}_{\mathrm{("Test\;Test\;Test")}} \, + \, \frac {{v}_{\mathrm{("Test\;Test\;Test")}} \, \cdot \, \frac{\mathrm{"Test\;Total"}}{\mathrm{"Test\;Total"}} }  {{\mathrm{K1}}_{\mathrm{("Test\;Test\;Test")}} \, + \, \frac{\mathrm{"Test\;Total"}}{\mathrm{"Test\;Total"}} }  } \right) } \right) } \\ 
\; && \;  { \, + \, {V}_{\mathrm{Test}} \, \cdot \, \left( { {{K}_{\mathrm{("Test\;Test\;Test")}} \, \cdot \, {\mathrm{[Test]}} }  \, \cdot \, \left( {{B}_{\mathrm{("Test\;Test\;Test")}} \, + \, \frac {{v}_{\mathrm{("Test\;Test\;Test")}} \, \cdot \, \frac{\mathrm{"Test\;Total"}}{\mathrm{"Test\;Total"}} }  {{\mathrm{K1}}_{\mathrm{("Test\;Test\;Test")}} \, + \, \frac{\mathrm{"Test\;Total"}}{\mathrm{"Test\;Total"}} }  } \right) } \right) } \\ 
&& \\ 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! `array` cannot span multiple pages. You are simply mistaken when you say that it can.

Comment: Also `\[...\]` can't span multiple pages as far as I know.

Comment: What you can do is converting this array of equations to the `align*` environment,  with the directive `\allowdisplay break`.